# Kendo ui Mobile Tabstrip does not select correct

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Normally when the Apps starts everything works fine.

now i have implemented my own i10n solution https://github.com/domiSchenk/phonegap-l10n/blob/master/localization.js

and i have a function to set the new Language (Localization.SetNewLang);
in this Function i invoke location.reload();

this works but sometimes one of my views does not get the id(line 12) correct, and i dont know why.

```
01. _back: false
02. _events: Object
03. _paramsHistory: Array[1]
04. _size: Object
05. applicationNativeScrolling: false
06. container: Object[1]
07. content: Object[1]
08. defaultTransition: ""
09. element: Object[1]
10. footer: Object[1]
11. header: Object[1]
12. id: "/"
13. init: function (e) {
14. inited: true
15. layout: Object
16. loader: Object
17. model: null
18. options: Object
19. overlay: Object[1]
20. params: Object
21. scroller: Object
22. scrollerContent: Object[1]
23. show: function (e) {
24. title: "({Setting.title})"
25. transition: undefined
26. wrapper: Object[1]
27. __proto__: Object
```

this has the effect that this view is not right selected in tabstrip.

does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could no find the bug of this problem.

what i did in the end is created static tabstrip.
this is archived with deleting data-role="tabstrip" form html.